# can react-route authentication be bypassed on client side?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I am using the react-route in my application.
And I am protecting my private pages using react-route PrivateRoute pattern (following react-route documentation) with JWT or firebase on top of it:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

As `fakeAuth.isAuthenticated` is taking place on the client side, could the user manipulate the authentication verification using the developer tools and get authenticated?(by setting isAuthenticated=true per example)

Or consider saving the user token in the localStorage. If the user sets the localStorage "user_id" manually from the console, then he would be considered authenticated, right?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as all your sensitive endpoints should have authentication on them too. Front end auth checking is just for UX flow never to hide something sensitive.

Comment: As long as you keep all your sensitive data on back end, that shouldn't matter

Comment: Thank you@DominicTobias @Dmitrri G. for your replies. So it is possible for a user to access the private UI if he manipulates the authentication verification on the client side. But I should protect my WEB APIs using JWT or something else.